# Making JW Player resposive

Tags: php, css, jwplayer, jwplayer6, jwplayer7

My code

```
function get_signed_player($videokey,$playerkey) {
  $path = "players/".$videokey."-".$playerkey.".js";
  $expires = round((time()+3600)/300)*300;
  $secret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
  $signature = md5($path.':'.$expires.':'.$secret);
  $url = 'http://cdn.jwplayer.com/'.$path.'?exp='.$expires.'&sig='.$signature;
  return $url;
};

echo "<p>Watch this cool video:</p>";
echo "<script type='text/javascript' src='".get_signed_player('xxxxxxx','xxxxxx')."' width=\"100%\"></script>";
```

It's working fine.
But, it's coming in fixed width.

[image: fixed width image]

How can I make it full width and responsive?

Can you help, please

Answer (score 0):

Your `players/` URL is loading a single-line JW Player embed that takes on all the characteristics of your player as defined in your JW dashboard. You have two options:

1) Edit the cloud-hosted player with player ID `$playerkey` in the JW dashboard to have desired responsive width and aspect ratio

2) Completely change your JW Player embed method to be completely manual:

- Load the player library URL on the page with the `libraries/` endpoint
- Include your  on the page with a unique ID
- Call Jwplayer('your_div_id').setup() and pass the desired parameters to load the video (file, image, width, aspectratio, etc)

Please see their documentation at https://developer.jwplayer.com/jw-player/docs/developer-guide/getting-started/add-an-html5-player/ for more details.